# bash search and replace replaces extra character

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to use bash' Parameter Expansion to replace a dollar-sign and am having trouble.  I've tried variations but nothing I've tried works, what am I doing wrong?  Example:

```
in_amt="($12.34)"
amt=${in_amt/$/}
echo $amt
```

produces (2.34) - the dollar-sign and the following "1" are removed

I've tried:

```
amt=${in_amt/[$]/[]}
amt=${in_amt/[$]}
amt=${in_amt/[\$]}
amt=${in_amt/\$}
amt=${in_amt/(\$/(}
```

and probably other variations all with the same result.  This is happening on two versions of bash: 3.2 (Macbook Air) and 5.0.17 (Ubuntu 20.04).

Replacing "normal" characters works.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the initial assign in single quotation marks because otherwise in the string `$1` is interpreted by the shell

```
in_amt='($12.34)'
amt=${in_amt/$/}
echo $amt
```

Or escape the `$` sign:

```
in_amt="(\$12.34)"
```

Comment: To demonstrate: `set -- hello; in_amt="($12.34)"; declare -p in_amt` outputs `declare -- in_amt="(hello2.34)"`

Comment: Thank you, discovered this the hard way after posting.